# Convert and Display the UTF8 Encoded String

Tags: java, android, unicode, nsstringencoding

I have a JSON response which i want to store in DB and display in text view or edit text. This json response is encoded by UTF-8 format.

Response is somthing like

```
 "currencies": [[0,"RUR"," ",1,0],[1,"EUR","â¬",1.44,100],[2,"GBP","Â£",1.6,100],[3,"JPY","Â¥",0.0125,100],[4,"AUD","$",1.1,100]]}
```

where â¬,Â£,Â¥ are currency symbol. I have to decode this and then display. This symbols are symbol in Unicode (transferrred as UTF8). How can I convert this encoded symbol. Plz help.

I tried this but it didnt works:

```
byte[] b = stringSymbol.getBytes("UTF-8"); // â¬,Â£,Â¥
final String str = new String(b);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're showing the *text* with non-currency symbols... it's as if you're taking the original text, then encoding that as UTF-8, then *decoding* it as ISO-8859-1.

It's just text - you shouldn't need to do anything to it afterwards, and you should never see it in this broken format. If you have to convert the text back to bytes and then to a string again, that means you've already lost, basically.

Check the headers on the HTTP response which returns the JSON - I suspect you'll find that it's claiming the data is ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8. The *actual* encoding has to match the encoding that's specified in the headers, otherwise you end up with this sort of effect.

Another possibility is that whatever's returning the JSON is accurately giving you the data that *it* knows about, and that the data is broken upstream. You should follow the data step by step (assuming you own all the links in the chain) until you can see where you're first encountering this brokenness.